# R format integer number by adding spaces

Tags: r, formatting

I have for example this integer number `number<-500000` or `number1<-1000000`.

I need format them like `[1] 500 000` `[1] 1 000 000`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use the `format` with `big.mark` argument

```
f1 <- function(num) {
        format(num, big.mark = ' ')
}

f1(number)
#[1] "500 000"

f1(number1)
#[1] "1 000 000"
```

Note that when we do `format` it changes `class` from `numeric/integer` to `character`